# optimal solution to filter elements from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of animals arr = ['cat','dog','elephant','lion','tiger','mouse']

I want to write a function remove(['dog','lion']) which can remove the elements from arr, and returns a new array, what is the best and optimal solution?

example:

```
arr = ['cat','dog','elephant','lion','tiger','mouse'] 
remove(['cat', 'lion'])
```

arr should get changed to

```
arr = ['dog','elephant','tiger','mouse']
```

Note: No Mutations

Comment: please check what mutation means.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you optimising for, efficiency or conciseness? How large are your arrays?

Comment: Well `filter` + `includes` in an arrow function make a pretty trivial solution.

Comment: @Bergi efficiency

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Then use a `Set` when removing many values

Comment: @Dij yes it did, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use `filter()`

```js
var arr = ['cat','dog','elephant','lion','tiger','mouse'];

var newArr = arr.filter(x => !['cat', 'lion'].includes(x))
console.log(newArr);
```